# Clamping during Tweening

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I'm using Greensock's TweenLite (AS3) for zooming in and out on a picture. It gets tricky when zooming out near the corners.
I am wondering if there's a way to clamp the width/height/x/y during tweening, so that it never goes out of bounds.

At the moment I have a 'fixer' method that I call when tweening is complete, but it's not ideal.

I've made a demo to show what I mean, try zooming out near a corner. (Mouse Scroll to zoom, click to pan...)

http://cloudchamber.knapnokgames.com/CCMedia/CCImageViewer/CCImageViewer.html

UPDATE: Here's the tweening code:

```
TweenLite.to(content, 0.3, { 
    width : _nativeWidth * newZoom , 
    height : _nativeHeight * newZoom,   
    x : (((content.x - origin.x) / content.width) * (_nativeWidth * newZoom)) + origin.x,
    y : (((content.y - origin.y) / content.height) * (_nativeHeight * newZoom)) + origin.y,
    onComplete: ClampContentPosition});
```

The X and Y calculations are maybe not the best, but they work. They took me a while to figure out ;)

Comment: Can you post the code where you're making your Tweenlite call?

Comment: I posted the code. But the more I think about it, I can probably optimize it somehow ...

Comment: you could do the calculation during each call in the onUpdate callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend running your logic **BEFORE** you even create the tween, thus you feed the tween the adjusted values in the first place. Or you could use an onUpdate as Neil suggested.